# How to remove my daughter as the AppleID organizer

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id, family-sharing

My daughter is the organizer for our family Apple account.  I'd like to remove her, my credit card is attached.  Can I do this without accessing her phone or do I need to cancel my credit card and create a new apple account?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; Don't cancel your AppleID, Do suspend the card or ask anyone using it to replace it whether they are in a family group or not. Then sort out the family sharing group - any account can leave at any time on their own. Then make a new group with the new organizer. Repeat leaving and joining as needed. Apple restricts each account to one family change a year, so be sure of your new plans before switching things up.

---

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201088

Since only the Organizer can disband the group, individuals may have to leave if the organizer is unavailable or unwilling to act. When this happens, only a temporary loss to updates of apps happens - no data is lost. Keep each account intact - no need to make new accounts unless someone is sharing an account and needs their own personal AppleID.

To switch the grouping - have the "soon to be new" organizer AppleID leave (voluntarily any account can leave or by having the organizer remove them). Then the new organizer makes a new family group as them as the new organizer.

At that point anyone is free to choose to stick with the old group or join the new group and when I say anyone - that's the action taken by each AppleID.

Billing needs to be sorted out on an account by account basis. Each AppleID has billing - and if you are not in control of that AppleID or can't wait for them - you have to cancel that card or suspend that card temporarily. This can happen no matter who is in the family group, or whether an account is an Organizer / Parent or member of the group.