# How do I change the organizer on my family sharing accounta

Tags: iphone

My ex husband is listed as the organizer in our family sharing account. He states he no longer has access to either his iCloud or @me accounts. My card is the one on file. How do I change the organizer to myself or cancel this account?

Answer (score 1):

In these cases official support and getting control of the main account are your best options. We can’t know all the details of what they can and will do, but this isn’t covered in the FAQ

- https://www.apple.com/family-sharing/
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201487

[Hopefully you don’t have to walk away from past purchases by losing control to the key account.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/393082/5472) Often with purchase details you can convince Apple you are not some hacker trying to take over someone else’s account. You having control over the payment card is a wonderful way for them to validate with official paperwork you are who you say you are. (As are legal contracts on marriage / divorce / other).

Note you can only switch families once a year, so measure twice before making a move.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201088

Answer (score 0):

The card is on file with the organizer account, not with the "family" as an entity. To resolve this issue you should do both of these things:

- Leave the Family
- Request a new credit card

If they are truly unable to access the account, then there is no risk to leaving the card on the account. However, to be safe I would still recommend getting a new card number.

You won't have authorization to access the account since, as I mentioned above, the card is attached to the other account, not to the family.

If you want to become a family Organizer, you must make a new Family after leaving this one.

Hope this all makes sense.